# how can I define uniform convergence in topological spaces, and also the concept of convergent series without talking about nets?

Tags: general-topology, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I have been in conflict with myself because of a confusion about the point convergence of sequences of functions and the uniform convergence over an arbitrary topological space. In metric spaces this concept is clear and can be defined in terms of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$. On the other hand, point convergence in topological spaces is stated in Munkres' book as follows:

A sequence $x_1, x_2, \ldots$ of points in a space $X$ converges to a point $x \in X$  if
for each neighborhood $U$ of $x$, $\exists N$ such that $\forall n \geqslant N$,
$x_n \in U$.

But how can I define uniform convergence in topological spaces,
and also the concept of convergent series without talking about nets?

I would greatly appreciate an answer on this topic.

Comment: I'm not an expert on the topic, but I believe that a topology is not sufficient for defining uniform convergence, and for this purpose, we have [Uniform Spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space).

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the concept of convergent series without talking about nets".  What difficulty do you have talking about convergent series?  What usage of nets do you not know how to eliminate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uniform convergence simply cannot be defined in a topological space, since it is not invariant under homeomorphisms.  For instance, consider the sequence of functions $f_n:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f_n(x)=\min(x,n)$.  If you equip the codomain $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard metric, then $(f_n)$ converges pointwise but *not* uniformly to the function $f(x)=x$.  However, if you instead equip $\mathbb{R}$ with a metric obtained by pulling back the standard metric on $(0,1)$ along a homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}\to(0,1)$, then $(f_n)$ does converge to $f$ uniformly.  Roughly speaking, this is because the metric thinks that real numbers going out to $\infty$ are instead going to $1$, so they get closer and closer together.

This means that it is not meaningful to talk about uniform convergence of functions $X\to Y$ if $Y$ is merely a topological space.  You need some additional structure on $Y$, such as a metric (or more generally, a [uniformity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space)).

Comment: Now I understand the concept. My question came from the proof of Tiezte's extension theorem which states that if $ X $ is a normal topological subspace and $ f $ a function defined in a subspace $ A \subset X $ with values ​​in $ \mathbb {R } $, then $ f $ can be extended to a continuous function defined on all $ X $.

Comment: The proof begins by saying: "the idea of ​​the proof is to construct a sequence of continuous functions $ s_n $ defined over the entire space $ X $, such that the sequence $ s_n $ converges uniformly, and such that the restriction of $ s_n $ a $ A $ gets closer and closer to $ f $ as $ n $ increases. Then the limit function will be continuous and its restriction to $ A $ will be equal to $ f $ ".

Comment: Later, in this same test, they consider a series $ g (x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{g_{n} (x)} $ for all $ x \in X $, where $ g_{n} \colon X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ and claim that this series converges. So, according to what you said in your answer above, if we are working on a topological space, why do they speak of uniform convergence of sequences of functions and convergent series?

Comment: The definition of uniform convergence uses only a metric on the *codomain* of the maps, which in this case is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you. Now everything is understood